# how do roweditor in Ext.create("Ext.window.Window") by extjs 4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How do roweditor in Ext.create("Ext.window.Window") by extjs 4.2.
Now, I can roweditor in grid,
but  I want to roweditor when Ext.create("Ext.window.Window") .

If there is an error in my code, please tell me!!

this is my extjs code,please help me!!!!!

```js
function sync1() {
    var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
    
    var data1=[];
    var rec = sm.getSelection();
   
    $.each(rec,function(i,item) {
     data1[i]=item.data.EQ_NO;
    });
    
        store1 = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store",
    {
     autoLoad : true,  //自動載入
     autoSync : false,  //false為批量修改,預設是false,true代表一經修改會自動呼叫下面的api動作
     proxy : {    //store資料來源地處理方式
      type : "ajax",
      api : {    //設定四種後端操作程式 (CRUD, 增讀改刪) 即可在編輯完畢後立即更新後端資料庫,保持前後端同步
       read : "pocServlet?action=test&eq_no="+ data1, 
       creat : undefined,
       update : "pocServlet?action=updateData",
       destroy : "pocServlet?action=deleteData",
      },
      reader : {
       type : "json",
       totalProperty : "totalProperty",
       //root : "root",
       //idProperty : "id"
      },
      writer : {
       type : "json",
       encode : true, //讓servlet能看懂
       writeAllFields : true,
       allowSingle : false,
       root : "data"   //後端getParameter的參數名稱
      },
      listeners : {//Exception Handler for the Ajax Request
       exception : function(proxy,response,operation) {
        var error = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        Ext.MessageBox.show({
         title : 'RULE DETAILS REMOTE EXCEPTION',
         msg : error.message,
         icon : Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
         buttons : Ext.Msg.OK
        });
       }
      }
     },
     listeners : {
      write : function(proxy,operation) {
       console.log("writeResponseText="+ operation.response.responseText);
       if (operation.response.responseText != 0) {
        alert("Pass");
       } else {
        alert("Fail");
       }
      }
     },
     fields : [
       {
        name : "EQ_NO"
       },
       {
        name : "REMARK"
       },
       {
        name : "POSITION"
       },
       {
        name : "MODIFY_USER"
       },
       {
        name : "MODIFY_DATE"
       }, 
     ]
    });
         columns1 = [{
     header : "EQ.NO.",
     dataIndex : "EQ_NO",
     width : 200,
     locked : true,
    }, {
     header : "Remark",
     dataIndex : "REMARK",
     width : 200,
     editor : {}
    }, {
     header : "Position",
     dataIndex : "POSITION",
     width : 200,
     editor : {}
    }, {
     header : "Modify_User",
     dataIndex : "MODIFY_USER",
     width : 200
    }, {
     header : "Modify_Date",
     dataIndex : "MODIFY_DATE",
     width : 200
    } ]
   
    win = Ext.create("Ext.window.Window", {
                    title: "Select Visit Vessel",
                    layout: 'fit',
                    maximizable: true,
                    width: 900,
                    height: 400,
                    tbar: {
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        frame: true,
                        border: false,
                        padding: 2
                    },
                    items: [{
                            xtype: 'grid',
                            store: store1,
                            columns: columns1,
                        }]
                });
                win.show();
   };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an fiddle example for you, to show how rowediting works:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/g2t

Basically you have to set the appropriate form field in the editor property you want to use as editing option.